# How to add event listener to the div element accessed with ref using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to add event listener to the div element using ref.

I add ref div_ref to Wrapper div and access that div_ref in  enableDragEventListeners method to add event listeners to that on componentmount.

Below is my code,

```
const SomeComponent: React.FC<any> = props => {
    const div_ref  = React.useRef(null);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const enableDragEventListeners = () => {
            const div = dropRef.current;
            if (div) {
                div.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragIn); // get error here
                div.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragOut); //error here
                div.addEventListener('dragover', handleDrag);//error here
                div.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);//error here
            } 
        };
        enableDragEventListeners();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Wrapper ref={div_ref}>
           {dragging && <Overlay>{props.children}</Overlay>}
        </Wrapper>
    );
}
```

But i get error property addEventListener doesnt exist on type 'never'. could someone help me fix this. thanks.

Edit: Complete code looks like this...i am implementing a draganddrop component so wrapping this around a component that wants to use this will be able to drag and drop files into it.

```
const DragAndDrop: React.FC<any> = props => {
    const dropRef = useRef(null);
    const [dragging, setDragging] = useState(false);
    const [dragCounter, setDragCounter] = useState(0);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        // componentDidMount()
        const handleDrag = (e: any) => {
            if (!props.loading) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
            }
        };

        const handleDragIn = (e: any) => {
            if (!props.loading) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev + 1);
                if (e.dataTransfer.files) {
                    setDragging(true);
                }
            } 
        };

        const handleDragOut = (e: any) => {
            if (!props.loading) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                setDragCounter((prev: number) => prev - 1);
                if (dragCounter === 0) {
                    setDragging(false);
                }
            }
        };

        const handleDrop = (e: any) => {
            if (!props.loading) {
                e.preventDefault();
                e.stopPropagation();
                setDragging(false);
                if (e.dataTransfer.files && e.dataTransfer.files.length > 0){ 
                    props.handle_drop(e);
                    e.dataTransfer.clearData();
                   setDragCounter(0);
                }
            }
       };
       const enableDragEventListeners = () => {
           const div = dropRef && dropRef.current;
           if (div) {
               div.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragIn);
               div.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragOut);
               div.addEventListener('dragover', handleDrag);
               div.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
           }
       };
       const disableDragEventListeners = () => {
           const div = dropRef && dropRef.current;
           div.removeEventListener('dragenter', handleDragIn);
           div.removeEventListener('dragleave', handleDragOut);
           div.removeEventListener('dragover', handleDrag);
           div.removeEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
       };
       setDragCounter(0);
       enableDragEventListeners();
       return () => {
           // componentWillUnmount()
           disableDragEventListeners();
       };
   }, [dragCounter, props]);

   return (
       <wrapper ref={dropRef}>
           {dragging && <Overlay>{props.children}</Overlay>}
       </Wrapper>
   ); 
};

const DropZone = styled.div``;

export default DragAndDrop;
```

Comment: hey, ddid my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why are you manually adding those event listeners via the component's ref, but since you are adding those event listeners when the component is mounted, you can bind those methods to the synthetic events.

```
<Wrapper 
  ref={div_ref}
  onDragEnter={handleDragIn}
  onDragLeave={handleDragOut}
  onDragover={handleDrag};
  onDrop={handleDrop}
>
```

Comment: thanks. i have updated my question with complete code...could you solution still be applied to the code. i think it should be but not sure about why adding event listeners on mount and unmount not good idea.

Comment: Potential issues as follows: You have to do the addition and clean up code yourself. If your `handle*` functions change on re-renders based on props or state, then you need to add to the dependency array of the effect to make sure it always fires, which means you'll need to add the cleanup. Applying it with the useEffect causes the events to be bound later in the lifecycle as well since useEffect runs after the mounting occurs. Another benefit of using React's bindings is that it's shorter, more explicit, and more local.

Comment: @someuser2491 yes, I have seen your updated code, and yes, I do believe my answer still apply.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue :**

```
const div_ref = React.useRef(null); // < --- due to null it type of div_ref becomes null
```

**Solution :**

```
const div_ref = React.useRef<any>(null); // <--- Provide type any
// OR
const div_ref = React.useRef<TYPE_OF_WRAPPER>(null); // <--- Provide the type of ref element
```

**Sample demo :** (With div element, you can remove the type and check, it will throw the same error )

[image: Edit SO - React Typescript]

---

> NOTE : And I think `dropRef.current;` should be `div_ref.current;`